# The problem with rendering the text in Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue instance called appDetails. This instance belongs to app.html. In it I declared function getApp, which returns the name of app:

```
var appDetails = new Vue({
  el: '#appDetails',
  methods: {
    getApp() {
      var path = url;
      var formData = "id=" + id;
        return axios.get(path, formData)
        .then((res) => {
           return res.data.name;
        })
    }})
```

Then in another js file I created product instance. This js file belongs to product.html. In it I declared computed property. In body of property I want to call a function of appDetails Vue instance. The returned data of the property is the name of app.

```
var product = new Vue({
  el: '#product',
  computed : {
    app_name: function() {
      appDetails.getApp()
        .then((returnVal) => {
          return returnVal;
        })
    }});
```

In product.html I wrote:

```
<a>{{app_name}}</a>
```

But when I load page, there is no text.  tag is empty.

But when I tried to console log it showed me a name.
Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you console.log `product`? Do you get a vue instance?

Comment: You could use `$parent` to call methods on the parent component or `$refs` to access child components, but the bigger issue is your computed property. The function must not be asynchronous.

Comment: @swonder yes, I get a vue instance

Comment: Try `{{product.app_name}}`

Comment: Two Vue instances placed in different html files, rendered at different routes within a normal website have ***nothing*** in common and they can't communicate with each other out of the box. In order to do it, you need to save data to be shared into either localstorage (browser storage) or on your server and when they activate (when you render the page containing one of them) they should get the data from where you've saved it and use it.

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for a [Mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app_name` resolves to `undefined` because the function does not return anything. Computed properties cannot be asynchronous, so instead you should create a data field on your component and call an asynchronous function that populates it. If you only need to fetch the data once, then `mounted` is probably a good place to do this.

```
var product = new Vue({
  el: '#product',
  data: function () {
    return {
      app_name: ''
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    appDetails.getApp()
      .then((returnVal) => {
        this.app_name = returnVal;
      })
  }
});
```

Also, does `getApp()` depend at all on the state of the AppDetails component? If not, it may make sense to keep it as a standalone function as it would be easier to use import it into both components.